# When inserting an HTML table row using jQuery some of the input elements do not work

Tags: jquery, html

I am inserting a table row after the current row by clicking on a button. The row is inserted as required; however, the input fields, after the first, and button at the end of the row are not working. The input fields can not be clicked on to add data; however, I can tab into them to add data. The button at the end of the row does not register a click. You can tab to the button and hit enter and it works (tabbing to it and clicking does not).

The existing row is:

```
//Add an initial row if there are not currently any program lines
var newRows = "";
    newRows += "<tr><td class='button'><button type='button' name='addPDRow'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></button></td>";
    newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='timeWidth pdValue' name='row0' value='07:00'></input></td>"; //Time
    newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='activityWidth  pdValue' name='row0'></input>" //Activity
    //Activity table
    newRows +=      "<table name ='activityTable'>";
    newRows +=          "<tbody name='activity2Tablebody'>";
    newRows +=              "<tr>";
    newRows +=                  "<td class='dropValue'>";
                                    //Put a transparent div over the inputs elements so it can be dragged to remove
    newRows +=                      "<div class='dragabbleRemove'><div>&nbsp;</div>";
    newRows +=                          "<input type='text' class='droppableItem activityWidth' disabled></input>";//Droppable Activity Class
    newRows +=                      "</div>";
    newRows +=                  "</td>";
    newRows +=              "</tr>";
    newRows +=          "</tbody>";
    newRows +=      "</table>";
    newRows +="</td>";

    newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='pdValue' name='row0'></input></td>";//Location
    newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='pdValue' name='row0'></input></td>";//Equip. Needed
    newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='pdValue' name='row0'></input></td>";//Youth to Bring
    newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='pdValue' name='row0'></input></td>";//Leaders
    newRows += "<td class='button'><button type='button' name='removePDRow'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></button></td></tr>";

$('#programDetailTablebody').append(newRows);
```

The function to add a new row is:

```
$('#programDetailTablebody').on('click', 'button[name="addPDRow"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newRows = "";
        newRows += "<tr><td class='button'><button type='button' name='addPDRow'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></button></td>";
        newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='timeWidth pdValue' name='row' value='07:00'></input></td>"; //Time
        newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='activityWidth  pdValue' name='row' value='activity'></input></td>"; //Activity       
        newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='pdValue' name='row' value=''></input></td>";//Location
        newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='pdValue' name='row'></input></td>";//Equip. Needed
        newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='pdValue' name='row'></input></td>";//Youth to Bring
        newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='pdValue' name='row'></input></td>";//Leaders
        newRows += "<td class='button'><button type='button' name='removePDRow'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></button></td></tr>";

    $(newRows).insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));

    $(makeDroppable);
});
```

This is what it looks like with the new row added:

[image]

Comment: Check the missing quote in the function - after `e.preventDefault()`, then, use the `$(document).on('click', '#programDetailTablebody button[name="addPDRow"]', ...` to **create the event click on the DOM.**

Comment: You are in dire, _dire_ need for at the very least an HTML templating solution, such as Handlebars. Keeping your HTML in your JS source code like this will make your life hard in more ways than one.

Comment: @RoyBogado Thank you and my apologies the line, I think you were referring to was part of my testing and I forgot to remove it. I have updated the code in my question. I have replaced the on click with your suggestion and that has not fixed the issue. What gets me is that the first two elements work (button and input).

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you for your advice I will take this under advisement and do some reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone mentioned to me "unless another element is layered over it capturing the mouse clicks." Brilliant! I have the following css:

```
.dragabbleRemove div {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Which pairs with:

```
//Put a transparent div over the inputs elements so it can be dragged to remove
newRows +=                      "<div class='dragabbleRemove'><div>&nbsp;</div>";
newRows +=                          "<input type='text' class='droppableItem activityWidth' disabled></input>";//Droppable Activity Class
newRows +=                      "</div>";
```

So the solution is more css:

```
    .pdValue {
        position: relative;
        z-index:3;
    }

    .buttonFront {
        position: relative;
        z-index:3;
    }
```

What I can not figure out is why the overlay is reaching down one row and to the right?

Kind regards,

Glyn